# What would I search for to find bike hubs that attach on only one side like found on tadpole recumbent

Tags: wheels, hub

What is the name of the hubs used on recumbent tadpole trikes. Those tricycles that have two front wheels and a conventional rear wheel

Comment: Their web site states "2 ea. Wheel Chair Hubs, with .5" axles"

Comment: @NateWengert this is a perfectly good answer, it should not be a comment.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46329/ but that's more about trailer wheels.  You'll need something with brakes as well.

Answer (score 2):

They are often referred to as just that, a tadpole trike hub assuming you're looking for the front hub. They differ from standard trike hubs slightly. If you are in the united states or Canada you can get on of these from a shop. Let me know what country you are in as you are unregistered and I will do my best to answer.

http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=38751

Comment: I am in California The link looks like it goes to a tadpole front hub But it has no axle and I can not tell if it is disc brake compatible or what is going on on the side. The link also gives no specs i.e. axle dimensions or number of spoke holes

Comment: It's a 36 hole, 6 bolt disc hub. The 36H in the description is the hole count, and the large flange on the right side is for the 6 bolt disc brake.

Comment: Axle : http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=38883

Answer (score 1):

Some DIYers repurpose pedal axles, e.g. starting at around 3:24 / 11:26 of [Tinny's busy day - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUzxohVQ-78)

Some pedals use the same bearings as front hubs; main challenges will be:
- threading/securing pedal axles into tadpole uprights.
- sorting pedals and hubs with compatible bearings and widths
- disassembling pedal and hub assemblies
- reassembly, replacing hub axles with pedal axles.

Comment: That's a really interesting thought.  Could you please summarise the main advantages and disadvantages, and give a brief outline of their process?  If the linked website ever goes away then this answer can stand alone.   Okay,  youtube's unlikely to vanish, but the video can be deleted, or it might someday go behind a paywall, any of which would rend this question into a kind-of dead-end.   Welcome to StackExchange!