# Trailer wheel: Axle connected on one side only

Tags: wheels, axle

Most wheels have an axle that needs to be connected to a frame from both sides. What are wheels called that only need to be connected from one side?

[image]

I'm looking to buy wheels like this and for that I need to know what they are called.

Comment: Reopened due to a flag that points out the linked dupe at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46329/ is specific to QR wheels.  Looking forward to answers about other sorts of connection, like Canonndale's Lefty and perhaps beam axles like a car trailer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is wheels with hubs that can accept or have a *stub axle*.

Googling 'bicycle trailer wheels', 'bicycle trailer hub' or 'wheelchair hub' will yield some results.

There are bicycle trailer kits available that include stub axle wheels, axle mounting brackets and hitches.